# Undesired offset when floating divs one next to the other

Tags: css, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .mydiv {
        width:300px;float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:250px;margin-right:10px
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1000px;clear:both">
      <div style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;">This is the title</div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;clear:both;width:1000px;margin-top:10px">    
      <div class="mydiv">Div</div>
      <div class="mydiv">Div</div>
      <div class="mydiv">Div</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the second and the third divs do not align properly (horizontally) with the first. For some reasons, a vertical offset makes the second and the third div appear a little lower than the first. Why is this?

Thankyou

#### PS

I am using Chrome 25, on MacOS X. Hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Move your CSS into a stylesheet. It'll make this so much easier to debug.

Comment: I have no idea why (because the float/clear model is insane), but removing the `clear:both;` from the parent `<div>` will fix the offset. It's a good idea anyway because it doesn't really make sense to add a `clear` there. `clear` only does something borderline sensible when the `clear`ed element **follows** a bunch of `float`ed elements, not when it **contains** them. (This is why "clearfix" hacks are so hairy.) In fact, "despite" the `clear`, the `<div>` containing the three `float`ed `<div>`s is `0px` tall.

Comment: Oh god... you are right!!! Please post your answer, you fixed this... btw I agree with you, the float/clear models sometimes is really really annoying... Thanks

Comment: I'm also with the suggestion of using HTML elements with sensible `id`s and a separate stylesheet. It might not make debugging easier per se, because the DOM inspector doesn't care where the rules come from, but it definitely makes reading the code sample easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly poking around tells me the way to fix the offset is to remove the `clear: both;` declaration from the parent `<div>` of the three `float`ed `<div>`s:

```
<div style="width: 1000px">    
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
</div>
```

To make the parent `<div>` "wrap around" the `float`ed `<div>`s, you need to add a `clear`ed `<div>` after the `float`ed ones:

```
<div style="width: 1000px">    
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

You can also use a "clearfix" (for instance [the one from HTML 5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css) on the containing `<div>` instead:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="width: 1000px">    
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
  <div style="…">Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have `clear: both;` on the *parent container* of the three red boxes, if you remove that property all three will be aligned as expected.

You need to include the clear property *after* the last floated closing `</div>` or you can use a clearfix which uses the `::after` pseudo-element *on* the container to clear floated elements within it.

You can see the container now respects the floated red boxes ..

[**jsBIN**](http://jsbin.com/ojayis/2)